# Extract the values from a specific key in a json file

Tags: javascript, object

I have a data which is this(I extract this from a json file):

```
    {
      data1:[
        "Hello",
       "How are you",
         "Are u alright"
         ],
      data2:[ "Hello",
      "How are you",
      "Are u alright",
      "HOwdy!"
      ]
   }
```

There is this thing that i need either the data1 values or data2 values i.e., array as a whole based on the input,,if i enter the input as data1 then data1 array should be stored in another value and vice versa.I tried using Object.keys() and filter functions and can't get the array as a whole.

Input:

```
         data1
```

Output:

```
       [
        "Hello",
       "How are you",
         "Are u alright"
         ]
```

Comment: please add an example of input and the wanted output.

Comment: Like you asked! @NinaScholz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the values using brackets notation like

```js
const obj = {
      data1:[
        "Hello",
       "How are you",
         "Are u alright"
         ],
      data2:[ "Hello",
      "How are you",
      "Are u alright",
      "HOwdy!"
      ]
}
const input1 = 'data1';
const input2 = 'data1';
console.log(obj[input1], obj[input2]);
```

Comment: Thank you Shubham for the answer